# PayPal IPN with PHP - EOF Exception

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm attempting Sandbox IPN transactions against various iterations of an IPN listener and continue to get the same error each time:

```
IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: Premature EOF; nested exception is java.io.IOException:     Premature EOF
```

The most recent API I've worked with is [here](https://code.google.com/p/paypal-ipn-class-php/), but it doesn't seem to matter which library I try out as I get the same error each time.

I've searched the hell out of this to no avail.  Can anyone tell me where to start?

Both scripts can be found here:

Listener Class: jamesbinford.net/other/ipnlistener.txt Listener itself: jamesbinford.net/other/ipn.txt

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm logging an Invalid Response Status: 302 as well, which is an INVALID paypal response.

Comment: I've alleviated the 302 problem and am now receiving valid PayPal responses from the Sandbox.

However, during testing I still get the EOF exception from PayPal.  I'm worried about going in to production with this error hanging over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I continue to receive errors in the PayPal sandbox, my requests are working as expected - whether I test success, failed, etc.

It appears to be an issue with PayPal's sandy.